# If :$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p =(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})\mod(p)$ how i deduce the remain of :$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-p}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, congruences

I have tried to determine  the remain of this serie:$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p$  :

I got this formula $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p =(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})\mod(p)$ ,where $p$

is prime and $k$  is positive integer .Now my question is :if what i got

is true then how do  I deduce the remain of this :$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-p}$

using $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p =(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})\mod(p)$?

note: $k^{-p}$ is inverse of $k$ modulo $p $ and I work in $\mathbb{Z_{p}}$

Any kind of help is appreciated.Thank you

Comment: Hmm. $\left(\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1}\right)^p$

Comment: p power hold only k

Comment: use the freshman's dream.

Comment: which is then $\sum_{k=1}^n k^{-1}$ by Fermat's little theorem

Comment: unless of course $n\ge p-1$ in which case you have the distinct problem of dividing by $0$ on one side or the other

Comment: yes, i find it by fermat's little theorem , thank you

Comment: What you got is true. I do not know what you mean by $\sum k^{-p}$.  It looks as if in general this is not an integer. If by $k^{-p}$ you mean the inverse of $k^p$ modulo $p$, this is not defined if $k$ is divisible by $p$.

Comment: I meant with k^(-p) general term of convergent series since p is prime

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing: do you work in the field $\Bbb Z _p$, where $k^{-1}$ is the inverse modulo $p$, or are you working in $\Bbb R$? In the latter case $\sum k^{-p}$ is rational but not integer, therefore it does not make sense to speak about integer division.

Comment: I meant is it possible by the same way of finding the recent claim to find the second where present a convergent series and I meant k^(-1) the inverse modulo p